# Is it compolsury to use manage.py shell in django project? I am creating a blog application

Tags: python, database, django-models, django-admin

Manage. Py shell is not convenient to me.is there any other way to import data into database.can i do it directly from admin panel?

Comment: yes you can just use psql to dump directly to the database ... or you can add the stuff one by one from the admin panel .... what do you mane when you say "not convenient for me"?

Comment: Actually i am very new to django framework. I have seen in a tutorial that the instructor  use shell and in another one he did not.but when i try to add stuff from admin panel it did not work properly.Can u give me some guideline.